# How to create an SVG path reveal animation in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, path, css, mask

[Handwriting: SVG animation CodePen Ex: 1](https://codepen.io/munkholm/pen/EaZJQE)

[Handwriting: SVG animation CodePen Ex: 2](https://codepen.io/Sector22/pen/KwNpWr)

I'm trying to learn how the above "handwriting" effect was achieved using SVG paths and CSS. I've been looking at the HTML and I also imported it into Illustrator to attempt to figure out what is happening. I'm new to Illustrator and my goal is to recreate this in Illustrator using another font.

My understanding thus far: the text, paths, and outlines were created. Then something called a `clip-path` was drawn through the entirety of the text. Something to do with masks? When you animate the `stroke` of the clip path it fills in all the spaces of the text.

How do you create this effect in Illustrator? Do I just create a normal path first with the pen tool and then convert it? Also, how would you organize the layers?

Edit: Lots of examples of SVG text animation on the web are animating the outline strokes of a font. Here the only thing being animated is a stroke that travels through an object ands fills in the spaces as it moves forwards in a linear animation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate Drawing of SVG Text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39178/animate-drawing-of-svg-text)

Comment: @Luciano That's not a good duplicate candidate. Joel is asking for how to set it up by hand in Illustrator while that question asks for a generic way to do it

Comment: @ZachSaucier true. Retracted.

Comment: There is a specific thing that is happening in that animation that I am asking about.

It has to do with a 'clip path' or 'masking path'. None of those questions is asking that. I'm also not looking for any outside tools to accomplish it. I just want to know how to create the clip path in illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...

Step 1: Make an object, text, square, circle, etc. If it's text make sure to convert to outline.

Step 2: On a layer below the object, draw a stroke.

Step 3: Highlight object and stroke, make sure object is layer above. Go to object, clipping path and then make. You should now be able to fill in the object with the stroke.

Step 4: Animate the stroke.